# CTE Query goes into Infinite Loop

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

My CTE runs in an infinite loop for a invoice and I am not able to find out why.

Postgress Version : EnterpriseDB 10.1.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit

Here is the query:

```
WITH recursive derived AS(
SELECT  inv_num, new_inv_num, 0 AS LEVEL
          FROM "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans o
         WHERE o.inv_num = '082003G10012730'
          AND o.new_inv_num NOT LIKE '%XX%'
           AND o.new_inv_num IS NOT NULL
           AND o.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
           AND o.attr_val IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT e.inv_num, e.new_inv_num, LEVEL + 1
          FROM "CBF".cbf_inv_gen_trans e
         inner join derived s ON s.new_inv_num = e.inv_num
         WHERE e.new_inv_num NOT LIKE '%XX%'
           AND e.new_inv_num IS NOT NULL
           AND e.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
           AND e.attr_val IS NOT null)
           SELECT new_inv_num
            FROM derived
           WHERE LEVEL = (SELECT max(LEVEL) FROM derived) limit 1;
```

Comment: A loop can occur with one row having `inv_num = new_inv_num`. Or two rows, one with `inv_num = 1 and new_inv_num = 2` and another with `inv_num = 2 and new_inv_num = 1`, or three rows with `inv_num = 1 and new_inv_num = 2` and `inv_num = 2 and new_inv_num = 3` and `inv_num = 3 and new_inv_num = 1`, etc. It should be `UNION ALL` btw., not `UNION`.

Comment: You should add a path array in order to detect cycles as shown in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Comment: Thanx..but still query goes into infinite loop..

Comment: In spite of using the path method? Please show your altered query then. Or did you answer to my first comment only?

Comment: After adding a path, query is executing in msec..Thanx for your quick support. Now query is working fine as expected.